# How to upload Multiple files using play framework?

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

i am using `play framework 2.1.2` **using java** and i am creating view to upload multiple files and my code is here :

```
@form(action = routes.upload.up, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
            <input type="file" name="picture" accept="application/pdf" multiple="multiple"><br/> 
            <input type="submit" value="upload"> 

            }
```

i want to upload only **doc and pdf file**.

**how to restrict form to upload only doc and pdf file ?**

i can this with java but i am looking for html code.

after this i want to store multiple file to permanent storage in my computer.

and print name of file i uploaded.

my code :

```
public static Result up(){


MultipartFormData md=request().body().asMultipartFormData();

        List<FilePart>file;

        file=md.getFiles();

        for(FilePart p: file){
        Logger.info(p.getFilename());
        }

        return ok(file.get(0).getFilename());
 }
```

it is **storing file into temp directory** but i want to **store to permanent location not on temp directory as a file not temp file** like if i upload `a.docx` i want to store **this file into storage** with `a.docx` name.

**i don't want to store file into database.**

and **how to list all file that i uploaded by file name?**

i found some question but i am not getting that answers because that question is for old version.

give me some idea to fix this issue.

Comment: check this link i hope it helps [FileUpload](http://www.erol.si/2014/10/handle-file-uploads-in-play-framework-2-x-java/)

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I implemented mine. I apologize if I made any mistakes somewhere. I "refactored" it so that it doesn't look anything like my production code.

In HTML I have:

```
<form name="fileUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@routes.Application.upload()">
        File 1: <br /> <input type="file" name="filePart1" id="filePart1"><br />
        File 2: <br /> <input type="file" name="filePart2" id="filePart1"><br />
</form>
```

In my controller I have:

```
public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

    FilePart filePart1 = body.getFile("filePart1");
    FilePart filePart2 = body.getFile("filePart2");

    File newFile1 = new File("path in computer");
    File newFile2 = new File("path in computer");

    File file1 = filePart1.getFile();
    File file2 = filePart2.getFile();

    InputStream isFile1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
    InputStream isFile2 = new FileInputStream(file2);

    byte[] byteFile1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(isFile1);
    byte[] byteFile2 = IOUtils.toByteArray(isFile2);

    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(newFile1, byteFile1);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(newFile2, byteFile2);

    isFile1.close();
    isFile2.close();
}
```

Just like Kris said, you will have to get Apache's CommonIO

You can easily do this buy adding this into your Build.scala found in /PlayProject/project:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.typesafe.config._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"  //add this here
  )
}
```

In this implementation, you can store the files anywhere on your computer where you specified in `File newFile1`. But you will have to use a database if you want to list your files. But you only have to store the file path as a String (varchar) in the database. I will leave that part up to you to figure out as I don't know how you want to handle file retrieval.

You can restrict user to only upload certain type of files by using Javascript. Have Javascript do form validation by checking the file name: Here is an example:

```
<script>
    var file1 = document.getElementById("filePart1").value;
    if (file1.indexOf(".pdf") == -1) {
        alert("Not a PDF file!");
    else {
        document.fileUploadForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Hope all of that helps.

Answer (score 4):

To get your file somewhere else than temp location you would need to copy it, best using something like FileUtils from apache commons (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

As for the file names you can get it from MultipartFormData

- First getFiles() [method](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.MultipartFormData.html#getFiles%28%29)
- Second getFile():File [method](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be is to use a custom body parser that can take a specified directory and save the uploaded files there. But you have to add some Scala code to the project. Here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/nraychaudhuri/6349808